# Can I highlight other parts of the status line with the Statuscolors patch?

Tags: nethack

The [wiki page for Statuscolors](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Statuscolors) (and every other resource I can find) shows how to color certain parts of the status line, and gives no information about coloring the rest. Is there any way to color anything else on the status line, and if so, what is the syntax?

Comment: Couldn't you just use names like `xp` and `time` instead of `hp` in the example commands?

Comment: The issue is that that page says to specify numeric fields by maximum percentage, but that doesn't reapply fit with fields like Exp or time, which can grow without bound, and aren't represented as percentages of a whole.